# Do i have British Citizenship by Descent if parents were born in a British overseas territory?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-citizenship

This has been confusing me for years. My mom and dad were not born in the UK, but both got British Citizenship within a British overseas Territory. I was also born outside of the UK, in 1986 and have gone to University in the UK for three years. With all of this, am I eligible to gain British Citizenship through my parents at my age?

Comment: Is the question whether you have British citizenship (at all)? Or whether you have British citizenship "by descent" vs. "otherwise than by descent"? Do you have a British passport? If so, what does it say in the "nationality" field?

Comment: Where were your parents and when? Where were you born?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the UK says:

> Under current legislation, British citizenship will normally descend through one generation to children born
>   abroad. Such children are British citizens by descent and are generally unable to transmit their citizenship
>   to subsequent generations born abroad.

If your parents were not born in the UK then you are not British yourself even if they were.

This is where I got it from:

[Home Office - Confirmation of British nationality status](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/322367/GUIDE_NS_-_June_2014-update.pdf)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's much more complicated than that.  In particular, it depends on the nationality law that was in effect at the time of the asker's birth, as well as the parents' birth, not current law, and on the status of the overseas territory, and so on.